# Is there any way to directly login users to firebase via google assistant? And if not is there any plan to implement that in future? #askfirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, actions-on-google

I'm creating an app that will run on the Google Assistant which should use firebase authentication to authenticate the user and then perform some user specific stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't currently possible for a user's Assistant account to automatically be linked to a Firebase Authentication account. You can create a basic OAuth2 server that uses Firebase Authentication to identify them as part of the Assistant [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) procedure, but this isn't done automatically. Once they have done the account linking, your Action will get an auth token (that your OAuth2 server has issued) and can use this to get a valid token to work with Firebase on their behalf.

Google doesn't typically announce future plans, however there have been a number of requests for similar features.